# Who should I try to recruit to help answer these questions?

Tags: discussion, participation, unanswered-questions, sponsorship-and-advertising, new-users

I would be willing to devote more of my time and energy towards increasing our user base to include experts in the following areas if you can let me know who the appropriate experts are!

Answer (score 3):

**[statistical-thermodynamics](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistical-thermodynamics), [polymers](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polymers), [mote-carlo](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mote-carlo) [correlation-functions](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correlation-functions)**

---

On 26 September 2021 a question was asked here which, after about six months of being unanswered, got a comment saying:

> "[You would get more answers if you asked easier questions lol :)](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6804/how-to-use-the-hnc-approximation-to-find-the-change-in-grand-potential#comment18486_6804)"

The same user that asked that question then asked 15 more questions, of which ***the most recent six*** of them have not been answered, and eight of them in total still remain unanswered, plus the one from September 2021:

- 2021 September: [How to use the HNC approximation to find the change in grand potential](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6804/5)
- 2021 December: [Some questions about implementing Swendsen-Wang algorithm](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8273/5) (now answered by Shern Ren Tee)
- 2022 February: [How does one convert the Improper Torsion Parameters from Tinker OPLS to a LAMMPS potential?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8659/5)
- 2022 March: [How to construct spinodal and binodal curves from a molecular simulation?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8830/5)
- 2022 June: [How to rigorously prove the existence of a coil-globule transition of polymers in an on-lattice simulation?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9198/5)
- 2022 July: [Statistical properties of semi-flexible polymers](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9326/5)
- 2022 July: [Why is my pdb looking so weird?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9382/5)
- 2022 July: [How to generate a polymer in different conformations?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9450/5) (now answered by Shern Ren Tee)
- 2022 August: [How do I calculate the acceptance criterion for configuration bias sampling of my polymer?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9525/5)

The same user had asked about two dozen questions before, and thankfully only three of them remain unanswered (though they were closed as abandoned):

- 2021 August: [How to go from tinker parameters to a GROMACS itp file, specifically for dihedrals?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4828/5)
- 2020 October: [Deriving relations for a hard sphere phase diagram](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3624/5)
- 2020 September: [Evaluating $C_v$ for one mole $H_2$ molecules in a quantum simulation](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2353/5)

I'll also say that some (additional) questions went unanswered for so long that the asker ended up having to answer them themselves (after several months):

- 2021 September (answered in 2022 June) [Discrete lattice polymer simulations](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6825/5)
- 2022 January (answered in 2022 September) [How to check for phase separation in polymer simulations?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8532/5)
- 2022 January (answered in 2022 September) [End-to-end correlation of polymers not decorrelating](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8626/5)

#### Many of these questions are extremely well-written and well-formatted

They seem entirely on-topic at MMSE, and show serious effort into the formatting and presentation. The author has been active quite consistently and has been helpful in writing self-answers for the benefit of future community members when they figured out the answer themselves (though all 7 of their answers were self-answers!).

I'd like to keep questions like these open on this site, and I'd like to continue encouraging such questions. However they have a very high unanswered rate which I find taxing when trying to help get things answered, and another user has said (see the top of this post) "You would get more answers if you asked easier questions lol :)" indicating that perhaps these questions require answerers with expertise in areas in which our current user base isn't very strong.

#### Does anyone have any recommendations about who the experts are in the field(s) covering the above questions, so that I can try to help recruit them to answer questions here?